# Equivalence of simlpy connected domain with existence of holomorphic square root

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I want to show the following:

*$D \subset \mathbb{C}$ is simply connected $\Leftrightarrow$ every zero-free holomorphic bijective function in $D$ has a holomorphic square root.*

I already proofed '$\Rightarrow$'.

I also have shown that $D$ is simply connected $\Leftrightarrow$ $D$ is homologically-connected (every loop in $D$ is nullhomologous in $D$).

So what I would like to do is to show that:

every zero-free holomorphic bijective function in $D$ has a holomorphic square root $\Rightarrow$ $D$ is homologically-connected.

Can you help me on that?